# PCs scores from Correlation and Covariance matrices through matrix computations and prcomp

Tags: r, pca, multivariate-analysis

I'm want to get PCs scores through matrix approach. My calculated PCs scores for correlation matrix matches with `prcomp` results but the PCs scores for covariance matrix do not match with the results of `prcomp`. Could you point out what am I missing? Thanks

**PCA on Correlation matrix**

```
# PCA on Correlation matrix
X <- USArrests
Cor <- cor(X)

EigenCor <- eigen(Cor)
ECor <- EigenCor$vectors
head(t(t(ECor) %*% t(scale(X))))


                 [,1]       [,2]        [,3]         [,4]
Alabama    -0.9756604  1.1220012 -0.43980366  0.154696581
Alaska     -1.9305379  1.0624269  2.01950027 -0.434175454
Arizona    -1.7454429 -0.7384595  0.05423025 -0.826264240
Arkansas    0.1399989  1.1085423  0.11342217 -0.180973554
California -2.4986128 -1.5274267  0.59254100 -0.338559240
Colorado   -1.4993407 -0.9776297  1.08400162  0.001450164

PCACor <- prcomp(x = X, retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
summary(PCACor)


Importance of components:
                          PC1    PC2     PC3     PC4
Standard deviation     1.5749 0.9949 0.59713 0.41645
Proportion of Variance 0.6201 0.2474 0.08914 0.04336
Cumulative Proportion  0.6201 0.8675 0.95664 1.00000

head(PCACor$x)
                  PC1        PC2         PC3          PC4
Alabama    -0.9756604  1.1220012 -0.43980366  0.154696581
Alaska     -1.9305379  1.0624269  2.01950027 -0.434175454
Arizona    -1.7454429 -0.7384595  0.05423025 -0.826264240
Arkansas    0.1399989  1.1085423  0.11342217 -0.180973554
California -2.4986128 -1.5274267  0.59254100 -0.338559240
Colorado   -1.4993407 -0.9776297  1.08400162  0.001450164
```

**PCA on Covariance matrix**

```
# PCA on Covariance matrix
Cov <- var(X)
EigenCov <- eigen(Cov)
ECov <- EigenCov$vectors
head(t(t(ECov) %*% t(X)))
                [,1]      [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
Alabama    -239.7035 -46.45394 -5.873077  5.7840485
Alaska     -267.7288 -39.91901 16.748431 -0.7178995
Arizona    -298.9695 -66.73235 -5.065592 -0.9775376
Arkansas   -193.2414 -41.19804 -3.167955  2.8551540
California -282.3243 -80.42202  3.367729  0.5643217
Colorado   -209.8773 -71.62154  8.901219  1.6546839



PCACov <- prcomp(x = X, retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = FALSE)
summary(PCACov)



Importance of components:
                           PC1      PC2    PC3     PC4
Standard deviation     83.7324 14.21240 6.4894 2.48279
Proportion of Variance  0.9655  0.02782 0.0058 0.00085
Cumulative Proportion   0.9655  0.99335 0.9991 1.00000

head(PCACov$x)
                 PC1        PC2        PC3        PC4
Alabama     64.80216 -11.448007 -2.4949328 -2.4079009
Alaska      92.82745 -17.982943 20.1265749  4.0940470
Arizona    124.06822   8.830403 -1.6874484  4.3536852
Arkansas    18.34004 -16.703911  0.2101894  0.5209936
California 107.42295  22.520070  6.7458730  2.8118259
Colorado    34.97599  13.719584 12.2793628  1.7214637
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Translating the answer of @ttnphns into `R`.

**PCA on Correlation matrix**

```
# PCA on Correlation matrix
X <- USArrests
Cor <- cor(X)

EigenCor <- eigen(Cor)
ECor <- EigenCor$vectors
head(t(t(ECor) %*% t(scale(X))))


                 [,1]       [,2]        [,3]         [,4]
Alabama    -0.9756604  1.1220012 -0.43980366  0.154696581
Alaska     -1.9305379  1.0624269  2.01950027 -0.434175454
Arizona    -1.7454429 -0.7384595  0.05423025 -0.826264240
Arkansas    0.1399989  1.1085423  0.11342217 -0.180973554
California -2.4986128 -1.5274267  0.59254100 -0.338559240
Colorado   -1.4993407 -0.9776297  1.08400162  0.001450164

PCACor <- prcomp(x = X, retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
summary(PCACor)


Importance of components:
                          PC1    PC2     PC3     PC4
Standard deviation     1.5749 0.9949 0.59713 0.41645
Proportion of Variance 0.6201 0.2474 0.08914 0.04336
Cumulative Proportion  0.6201 0.8675 0.95664 1.00000

head(PCACor$x)
                  PC1        PC2         PC3          PC4
Alabama    -0.9756604  1.1220012 -0.43980366  0.154696581
Alaska     -1.9305379  1.0624269  2.01950027 -0.434175454
Arizona    -1.7454429 -0.7384595  0.05423025 -0.826264240
Arkansas    0.1399989  1.1085423  0.11342217 -0.180973554
California -2.4986128 -1.5274267  0.59254100 -0.338559240
Colorado   -1.4993407 -0.9776297  1.08400162  0.001450164
```

**PCA on Covariance matrix**

```
# PCA on Covariance matrix
Cov <- var(X)
EigenCov <- eigen(Cov)
ECov <- EigenCov$vectors
head(t(t(ECov) %*% t(scale(x = X, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE))))

                 [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
Alabama     -64.80216  11.448007 -2.4949328  2.4079009
Alaska      -92.82745  17.982943 20.1265749 -4.0940470
Arizona    -124.06822  -8.830403 -1.6874484 -4.3536852
Arkansas    -18.34004  16.703911  0.2101894 -0.5209936
California -107.42295 -22.520070  6.7458730 -2.8118259
Colorado    -34.97599 -13.719584 12.2793628 -1.7214637

# Here is the change
PCACov <- prcomp(x = X, retx = TRUE, center = TRUE, scale. = FALSE)
summary(PCACov)



Importance of components:
                           PC1      PC2    PC3     PC4
Standard deviation     83.7324 14.21240 6.4894 2.48279
Proportion of Variance  0.9655  0.02782 0.0058 0.00085
Cumulative Proportion   0.9655  0.99335 0.9991 1.00000

head(PCACov$x)
                 PC1        PC2        PC3        PC4
Alabama     64.80216 -11.448007 -2.4949328 -2.4079009
Alaska      92.82745 -17.982943 20.1265749  4.0940470
Arizona    124.06822   8.830403 -1.6874484  4.3536852
Arkansas    18.34004 -16.703911  0.2101894  0.5209936
California 107.42295  22.520070  6.7458730  2.8118259
Colorado    34.97599  13.719584 12.2793628  1.7214637
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't know R but can see your mistake. When you do it with correlations, you correctly multiply **standardized** data by the eigenvectors (I guess it's `scale(X)` which standardizes) to get the PC scores.

When you analyse covariances, you must multiply **centered** data by the eigenvectors. But instead, you are multiplying **raw** data by the eigenvectors. Hence you get incorrect scores.